# Свойства "background", устанавливаемое в разных местах

Tags: html, css, css3

Одно изображение задается стилем прямо в разметке, и другое в качестве узора должно выводиться поверх него, задаваясь стилями. Можно реализовать такое без использования дополнительных элементов, при помощи только множественного значения для свойства `background`?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh6efbv8/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Для множественного background нужно задавать все фоны в одном месте. Нельзя один там, другой там.

Используйте псевдоэлемент для наложения узора.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 168px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('http://meditationsema.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pattern4-240x300.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style = "background-image: url('https://sky-wall.ru/uploads/source/2015/02/preview/2669f87a3e17494358dcae5da33088af.jpg')"></div>
```